# A note on graphics::curve() in R CMD check

Tags: r, r-package

I use the following code in my own package.

```
 graphics::curve( foo (x) )
```

When I run R CMD check, it said the following note.How do I delete the `NOTE`?

```
> checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE
  foo: no visible binding for global variable 'x'
  Undefined global functions or variables:
    x
```

---

**Edit for the answers:**

I try the answer as follows.

```
function(...){
   utils::globalVariables("x")
   graphics::curve( sin(x) )
}
```

But it did not work. So,..., now, I use the following  code, instead

```
function(...){
   x <-1 # This is not used but to avoid the NOTE, I use an object "x".
   graphics::curve( sin(x) )
}
```

The last code can remove the NOTE.

Huuum, I guess, the answer is correct, but, I am not sure but it dose not work for me.

Comment: Where are you expecting `x` to reside (environment) ?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Add

   ```r
   utils::globalVariables("x")
   ```

   This can be added in a file of its own (e.g., `globals.R`), or (my technique) within the file that contains that code.

   It is not an error to include the same named variables in multiple files, so the same-file technique will preclude you from accidentally removing it when you remove one (but not another) reference. From the help docs: *"Repeated calls in the same package accumulate the names of the global variables"*.

   This must go outside of any function declarations, on its own (top-level). While it is included in the package source (it needs to be, in order to have an effect on the `CHECK` process), but otherwise has no impact on the package.
2. Add

   ```
   importFrom(utils,globalVariables)
   ```

   to your package `NAMESPACE` file, since you are now using that function (unless you want another `CHECK` warning about objects not found in the global environment :-).